# Is my username and password sent plaintext when connecting to my remote sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Is our username and password that is sent over the network to connect to a 2008 sql db plaintext?

For instance

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

Is the password and username sent plain text to the server for the initial handshake?

Comment: Did you get a valid answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

This TechNet article claims that the credentials for SQL 2008 are always encrypted:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.100).aspx

> Credentials (in the login packet) that are transmitted when a client
>   application connects to SQL Server are always encrypted.

There are optional items you can add to your connection string that will also enable encryption for other types of SQL Server communication that may be worth investigating if point-to-point security is a concern for your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: Without any certificate how can it be encrypted?

Comment: The linked article explains how to set up a certificate for SQL Server to use, and says that if you do not set one up, SQL Server will generate a self-signed certificate to use.

Comment: The article has no mention about self signed certificate to encrypt credentials plesse can you check this and let me know where it says so please